# Working out what commands do

Tags: linux

How do I find out what commands such as LS do? I have recently been trying to write my first code and have became stuck with command names.

Comment: Please use search engines before asking - this is not really worth an answer. What you are probably looking for is "unix command cheat sheet" or something like that.

Comment: You and your mates have been posting a lot of bad content. Please read the [help] and familiarize yourself with what types of questions we consider on topic. Copying each other's answers is a no-no and posting non-answers is also unacceptable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `man` command in front of whichever command you are unsure about. For example

```
man ls
```

That will show you the program's manual ("Man" is short for manual).

Comment: You and your mates have been posting a lot of bad content. Please read the [help] and familiarize yourself with what types of questions we consider on topic. Copying each other's answers is a no-no and posting non-answers is also unacceptable.

Answer (score 4):

`man`is your friend.

```
man ls
```

will show you a help page for command `ls`